# Salesforce connector uri endpoint failure

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, salesforce, jbossfuse

I´ve an issue with the salesforce connector uri.

Here is the error:

`Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: salesforce://query?ObjectClass=org.apache.camel.salesforce.dto.QueryRecordsAccount&sObjectQuery=SELECT+Id%2CName+FROM+Account due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: salesforce://query?ObjectClass=org.apache.camel.salesforce.dto.QueryRecordsAccount&sObjectQuery=SELECT+Id%2CName+FROM+Account due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{ObjectClass=org.apache.camel.salesforce.dto.QueryRecordsAccount}]`

And here is my route:

`route id="timerToLog">
            <from id="_from1" uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="salesforce:query?sObjectQuery=SELECT Id,Name FROM Account&amp;sObjectClass=org.apache.camel.salesforce.dto.QueryRecordsAccount"/>
            <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo1" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="Query result back from Salesforce:${body}"/>
        </route>`

What´s the problem? How i configure the endpoint correctly? Did i miss something?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The option is named `sObjectClass` as documented at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-salesforce/camel-salesforce-component/src/main/docs/salesforce-component.adoc

Comment: Thank you Claus, i´ve just forgiven the "s" as prefix.